# Flask's SQLAlchemy isn't rolling back the appropriate transaction?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, pytest

I have a simple series of integration tests that I want to issue a rollback after each tests. The problem I'm facing is that while I see a rollback statement issued in the console (I have `SQLALCHEMY_ECHO = True` in my configuration), the data is still present in the database. Obviously, I would expect the data I insert after every test to be gone from the database.

Here is an example with just enough code to trigger my issue -

```
import pytest
from app import create_app
from app import db as _db
from app.main.models import Customer


@pytest.yield_fixture(scope='session')
def app():
    app = create_app('testing')
    app_ctx = app.app_context()
    app_ctx.push()

    yield app

    app_ctx.pop()


@pytest.yield_fixture(scope='session')
def db(app):
    _db.app = app
    _db.create_all()

    yield _db

    print('drop_all()')


@pytest.yield_fixture(scope='function')
def session(db):
    conn = db.engine.connect()
    trans = conn.begin()
    session = db.create_scoped_session(options={ 'bind': conn })
    db.session = session

    yield session

    trans.rollback()
    conn.close()
    session.remove()


def test_foo(session, app):        
    cust = Customer(name='foo')
    session.add(cust)
    cust2 = Customer(name='bar')
    session.add(cust2)
    session.commit()

    client = app.test_client()
    response = client.get('/api/customers')

    from json import loads
    json_response = loads(response.data.decode('utf-8'))
    custs = json_response['customers']

    assert len(custs) == 2
    assert custs[0]['name'] == 'foo'
```

SQLAlchemy log -

```
2015-09-24 13:56:27,601 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2015-09-24 13:56:27,667 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2015-09-24 13:56:27,669 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO customers (name) OUTPUT inserted.id VALUES (?)
2015-09-24 13:56:27,669 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('foo')
2015-09-24 13:56:27,715 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO customers (name) OUTPUT inserted.id VALUES (?) 
2015-09-24 13:56:27,715 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('bar')
2015-09-24 13:56:27,749 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
2015-09-24 13:56:27,779 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit) 
2015-09-24 13:56:27,779 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT customers.id AS customers_id, customers.name AS customers_name FROM customers 
2015-09-24 13:56:27,780 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2015-09-24 13:56:27,827 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ROLLBACK
2015-09-24 13:56:27,827 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ROLLBACK
```

As you can see I there are 3 implicit transactions being started, but only 2 rollbacks. Why isn't the transaction that I'm beginning during the test session being rolled back?

I've read SQLAlchemy's documentation with regards to rolling back during tests, but nothing sticks out.

Answer (score 0):

Dirty hack in fixture. Helps me

```
tmp_engine = db.engines[None]
connection = db.engine.connect()
transaction = connection.begin()
db.engines[None] = connection
yield db.session
db.session.remove()
transaction.rollback()
connection.close()
db.engines[None] = tmp_engine
```